# Can capital ships make accurate micro-jumps through Hyperspace without aiming for a gravity well?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, hyperspace

For a large portion of *The Last Jedi*,

> the First Order fleet is chasing the remnants of the Resistance fleet through space, but they are unable to catch up until the Resistance ships run out of fuel.

I've seen a number of suggestions for how the First Order might have better handled this situation, including the idea that they perform a micro-jump through Hyperspace to close the distance or get ahead of the Resistance.

However, this might not be technically possible. Every example of a micro-jump I can think of relies on taking advantage of an existing gravity well -- a planet, or an interdictor -- to "force" the early drop from Hyperspace.

Is there any precedent in canon of a capital ship performing a targeted micro-jump through Hyperspace without the use of a gravity well to assist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the (canon) novel [Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel)), a Support Carrier uses precisely this technique to suddenly jump into fighter-range of an opponent.

> “Transponder signature identifies it as the Goliath,” Cala continued. “Capable of carrying a wing of starfighters. Armed with ten Taim and Bak H-eights and a Krupx missile delivery system. Not much in the way of shields—”
>   “I’m not interested in testing its mettle,” Teller said.
>   “It could be here simply to refuel,” Artoz said, sounding unconvinced.
>   Abruptly, the escort vanished from the screen.
>   “Where’d it go?” Anora asked.
>   And just as abruptly the escort reappeared—now visible through the forward viewports.
>   “Microjump!” Cala said. “And deploying starfighters!”

We can suppose that Snoke's ships didn't try this trick because of the proximity of multiple planets in the vicinity and the fact that there was extremely limited navigational data available, making a micro-jump into a suicide mission.

Comment: Is there anything in the novel about the surrounding system, where this manoeuver took place? If they planned the ambush, they could have placed themselves exactly in one of the few spots where such a jump is possible in a system?

Comment: @Falco - They were in a system, relatively close to a planet. The system was a high-traffic area with multiple inhabited planets, various moons and multiple known "jump points". I would imagine that it was extensively mapped.

Comment: thank you, this fits nicely into canon. So if one side has extensive mapping data of a system, they can jump and ambush the other side. But if one side follows the other into uncharted territory, micro jumps are not feasible.