# Why didn't the bombers drop out of hyperspace closer to the Dreadnought?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, hyperspace

Why didn't the bombers use hyperspace to get closer to the Dreadnought before starting their attack run? The slow approach caused the majority of the fleet to be destroyed.

As we saw later in the film, when Rey is ejected in an escape pod, ships are perfectly capable of dropping out of hyperspace, delivering a payload, and then immediately entering hyperspace again.

In The Force Awakens, Han Solo didn't seem to have any problem dropping the Millenium Falcon out of hyperspace remarkably close to Starkiller Base to avoid detection. It appears that such a maneuver is not only possible but could be used frequently.

Comment: "didn't seem to have any problem"? what about crashing and almost falling off a cliff? I'd say it was a risky move and they just got lucky that they didn't die

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176689/can-capital-ships-make-accurate-micro-jumps-through-hyperspace-without-aiming-fo

Answer (score 12):

Remember that Han Solo's little hyperspace trick in TFA wasn't exactly regarded as *sane*. Hyperspace just isn't that precise.

Second, when Chewie drops Rey off, she's a good distance away from the *Supremacy* and her Star Destroyers. It takes her escape pod some time to maneuver into the bay. In other words, she's not close enough to be a bomb.

The third reason is they didn't need to. The plan was Poe was going to clear the deck of turbolasers and they would have all the time they needed to complete an attack run. Which it did... kinda. If you count losing all their bombers as a successful attack. Which Leia did not.

Answer (score 2):

What you really asking is how [precise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176689/can-capital-ships-make-accurate-micro-jumps-through-hyperspace-without-aiming-fo) are [micro-jumps](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Micro-jump) ?

In current canon this is somewhat unclear, but we have clues that CEP of such jump is at least few kilometers. As you mentioned, Solo managed to jump into atmosphere of Starkiller Base, therefore avoiding the shields, but his was done at great risk. Atmosphere of planet is usually measured in dozens of km.  Before that, Anakin Skywalker managed to jump [few kilometers from Grievous ship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous_Intrigue).

Both fits were done by exceptional pilots and in exceptional circumstances. Could average bomber pilot do the same, reliably every time ? Most likely no, and even if they managed to repeat what Solo or Anakin did, they would still not be over target to bomb it. Instead, they did what they could and trained for, slow approach formation run.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The bombers didn’t jump out of hyperspace. They were on board the Raddus. Remember in the novel when Paige notes she felt “faint jostling as conduits and hoses were uncoupled,” and “the sight of the flight deck a mere meter below,” the “glass globe enclosing her” and “then there was nothing below her but black and endless space.” This is the bomber taking off from a hangar aboard the Raddus.

Comment: You're missing the point. The question is asking why, after exiting the Raddus, did they travel in normal space (subject to the enemy guns) when they could have traversed the same distance in a fraction  of a second in total safety in hyperspace?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but the question seems to be asking "why *didn't* they drop out of hyperspace", to which "they didn't jump out of hyperspace" isn't really an answer.